# Scrollbar width in Qt applications

Tags: gtk, qt, scrollbar

I have made the scrollbar width for Gtk applications wider,

> Create a file called ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
>
> Containing scrollbar slider { /* size of the slider */ min-width:
>   20px; min-height: 20px; border-radius: 22px; /* padding around the
>   slider */ border: 5px solid transparent; }

but this doesn't work properly for LibreOffice and doesn't work for CherryTree which is a Qt application.

What do I need to do for LibreOffice and for Qt applications?

Comment: You should always provide information re. your distro, its version, the desktop environment and any other information you feel maybe helpful to those trying to help. If, based on some other question by you, LibreOffice is a snap, you need to mention that.

Comment: DK Bose Could you provide information re. "some other question by you, LibreOffice is a snap". If you are referring to another post by me please mention the site and thread.

Comment: I have found Qt5 Settings which allows the selection of style sheets and the creation of a  new one. These are in /usr/share/qt5ct/qss and sliders-simple.qss looks interesting. It has QSlider::groove:..........vertical width: 10px; which I tried changing to 25 with no effect. Worth looking into though.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar following advice on another website.

I created the following in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```css
scrollbar, scrollbar button, scrollbar slider {  
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;  
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;  
    min-width: 20px;  
    min-height: 20px;  
    border-radius: 0;  
}
```

This works in both Firefox and LibreOffice for me.

I seem to remember that Libreoffice was lagging behind on the GTK front not so long ago, in which case you might want to try upgrading or fiddling with your current window theme GTK2 CSS file in `/usr/share/themes/your-theme-name/gtk-2.0/`

Comment: Before editing anything LibreOffice was okay, must have been updated since my OP last April. The gtk2 css was similar to what is in your post, but a bit simpler, and if I copy yours the stepper doesn't work, perhaps that was an addition in 3.0? That's fine though. I've noticed that there is an empty file in the gtk-4.0 directory too, ready for the allegedly imminent release of gtk4 I suppose. Thanks for reminding me of this problem, I'll know what to do when 4 comes out.