# Ubuntu 22.04 change scrollbar width

Tags: gtk, gedit, scrollbar

In Ubuntu 22.04 I have tried to edit the Yaru-blue theme gtk.css file to make the scrollbar wider.

I entered

`sudo gnome-terminal`

to open a second terminal as root. In that root terminal I entered

`cd /usr/share/themes/Yaru-blue/gtk-4.0`

then entered

`gedit gtk.css`

to edit the css file.

In the gedit window below the line

```
@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru-blue/4.0/gtk.css");
```

I entered

```
scrollbar slider { min-width: 20px; min-height: 20px; border-radius: 22px; border: 5px solid transparent; }
```

and saved the file.

In the root terminal window I saw

```
** (gedit:297357): WARNING **: 16:14:44.503: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported
```

The scrollbar width was unchanged; i.e. very narrow.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question was taken from an answer to a similar question that was posted at [Scrollbar width in Qt applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229402/scrollbar-width-in-qt-applications?rq=1) on Jan. 11, 2021

The solution is to edit the file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css by adding the code

```
scrollbar, scrollbar button, scrollbar slider {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;
  min-width: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

This works in Ubuntu 22.04 and does not require being root.

Answer (score 1):

Prior answers are great for editing the config files.

I thought this might be an alternative readers would want to know about.

Themes app / Settings / Scroll bar behavior / Override the current theme's scrollbar width